# No data return in Modal when some row values are null

Tags: php, mysql, json, ajax, bootstrap-modal

I am working on a project, where I have created a catalog for company. On some pages when user clicks on product id, a modal displays product detail. The modal works fine when there are values in rows.  However, when there are null values, the modal comes back empty. How do I handle the code so that even if there are null values in some rows, data will still be displayed? Or is there an easier way to show show product detail without using modal/ajax/json.

## MYSQL Query

```
if($_REQUEST['tid']) {
SELECT t.tool_id, power_source, sub_option, sub_type, 
(purchase_price * 0.15) AS rental_price, (purchase_price * 0.4) AS 
deposit_price, material,manufacturer, length, width_diameter, weight, 
ac.accessory_description FROM tool t JOIN accessory ac on t.tool_id = 
ac.tool_id WHERE tool_id='".$_REQUEST['tid']."'";
$resultset = mysqli_query($connection, $sql) or die("database error:". 
mysqli_error($connection)); 
$data = array();
while( $rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultset) ) {
$data = $rows;
}
echo json_encode($data);
} else {
echo 0; 
}
?>
```

## Ajax/json code

```
$(document).ready(function(){$(document).on
('click', '#getTool', function(e){  e.preventDefault();  
var tid = $(this).data('id');    
$('#tool-detail').hide();
$('#tool_data-loader').show();  
$.ajax({url: 'toolData.php',
type: 'POST',
data: 'tid='+tid,
dataType: 'json',
cache: false
})
.done(function(data){
console.log(data.id); 
$('#tool-detail').hide();
$('#tool-detail').show();
$('#tid').html(data.tool_id);
$('#tool_type').html(data.power_source);
$('#short_desc').html(data.sub_option + " " +data.sub_type);
$('#fullDesc').html(data.manufacturer+ " "+data.material+ ", 
"+data.length+"in x " +data.width_diameter+"in,"+data.weight+"lbs");
$('#rental_price').html("$"+data.rental_price);
$('#deposit_price').html("$"+data.deposit_price);
$('#accessories').html("$"+data.accessory_description);      
$('#tool_data-loader').hide();
})
.fail(function(){
$('#tool-detail').html('Error, Please try again...');
$('#tool_data-loader').hide();
});
}); 
});
```

## Modal

```
<form action="productDetail.php" method="post">
<table>
<tr>
<td><input type="submit" name="productDetail" value="productDetail" id="productDetail" style="margin-left: 10px;"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
<div id="tool-modal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;">
<div class="modal-dialog"> 
<div class="modal-content">                  
<div class="modal-header"> 
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">*</button> 
<h4 class="modal-title">
<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-wrench"></i> Tool Details
</h4> 
</div>          
<div class="modal-body">                       
<div id="tool_data-loader" style="display: none; text-align: center;">
<img src="ajax-loader.gif"> 
</div>                       
<div id="tool-detail">                                        
<div class="row"> 
<div class="col-md-12">                         
<div class="table-responsive">                             
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
<tr>
<th>Tool ID</th>
<td id="tid"></td>
</tr>                                     
<tr>
<th>Tool Type</th>
<td id="tool_type"></td>
</tr>                                         
<tr>
<th>Short Description</th>
<td id="short_desc"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th>Full Description</th>
<td id="fullDesc"></td>
</tr>                                            
<tr>
<th>Rental Price</th>
<td id="rental_price"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th>Deposit Price</th>
<td id="deposit_price"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th>Accessories</th>
<td id="accesories"></td>
</tr>                                                                                           
</table> 
</div>                                       
</div> 
</div>                       
</div>                              
</div>           
<div class="modal-footer"> 
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>  
</div>              
</div> 
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have a look at the syntax highlighting in your first snippet. Does it look right?

Comment: Maybe try the MySQL [coalesce](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/comparision-functions-and-operators/coalesce-function.php) function with an empty string replacing the null values?